# Centering text on a background image

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a   with a background image. It contains an other  to display a total price.

[**Live demo**](http://jsbin.com/wabolamaji/edit?html,css,output)

When the device screen is small, the number 0 to display is centered in the middle and base of the background image:

[image]

When I resize the screen (larger) the number is not longer cenetered as on the first screenshot:
[image]

How can I 0 displayed after resizing the screen to larger width as on the first picture ?

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest to give the 0-div a static width:

```
    .total{
 position:absolute;
 background-color:aqua;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size:10px;
 text-align:center;
 width: 40px;    <---- 
 left: 5%;
 bottom:14px;
}
```

Comment: Ditto for the left value...about 5px should be about right...otherwise it will move.

Answer (score 2):

add this

```
.divThree:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and change .total

```
.total{
    background-color:aqua;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 90%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SureshGogu/7L1kjnkg/)